# SQL Server Order By (Select Clause from Table)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have this query below, it compiles and runs but doesn't do the job of sorting.

```
declare @sort table (sort varchar (500))
insert into @sort values ('Code DESC')

SELECT * FROM  Registry
ORDER BY (select sort from @sort)
```

Is the approach OK?

If I need to select the sort clause of order by from a table where its stored as string what can be the options or this is a lost cause.

Actually I have a sort table with various bit values (6 columns of bit values) and using those permutations in a CASE WHEN wouldn't be comprehendable, and I cannot use Dynamic SQL

Answer (score 0):

you need to do dynamic SQL here. Try a code like below

```
DECLARE @query varchar(max);
SET @query= 'SELECT * FROM  Registry ORDER BY '+ (select TOP 1 sort from @sort)
EXEC(@query)
```

In case you have multiple entries in your table for sort, you should also consider storing order of sorting in the table.

```
declare @sort table (sort varchar (500), orderCol int)
insert into @sort values ('Code DESC', 1),('Name DESC', 2)

DECLARE @query varchar(max);
SET @query= 'SELECT * FROM  Registry ORDER BY '+ 
SELECT Stuff((select N', ' + sort from @sort order by orderCol ASC FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'')
EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: Yes I can, but this has to be applied at much larger code where code maintenance would be cumbersome and Dynamic SQL is strict no no